# Jenkins setup fails - Error "Non-resolvable import POM"

Tags: java, jenkins, pom.xml, s4sdk

I am trying to setup a Continuous Delivery pipeline using Jenkins for the address-manager application built using Java and S4/HANA Extension SDK.

I have followed the instruction and tried to implement along the lines of Week 3 - Unit 2 material of this [course](https://open.sap.com/courses/s4h13). But upon starting Jenkins and starting the app for pipeline build on localhost, I see that the job which I schedule as a multi branch fails.

I have checked the logs of the same and can see that it has failed because of this error:

```
`[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing
the POMs: 16:51:13  [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not 
find artifact com.sap.cloud.s4hana:sdk-bom:pom:2.8.1 in s4sdk-mirror 
(http://s4sdk-nexus:8081/repository/mvn-proxy/) @ line 16, column   
25`
```

Request any help or pointers to proceed, so that I am able to deploy it successfully. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that Docker has not enough memory. As mentioned in the video, at least 4 GB is required, even for simple projects. To verify, you can run `docker ps`. It should list at least two containers, one is called `s4sdk-jenkins-master` and one `s4sdk-nexus`. It looks like the nexus container was killed because Docker did not have enough memory.

To fix this, please go into the Docker settings, and provide 4 GB of memory, re-start Docker and repeat what you did.

In case it is not possible to provide 4 GB memory due to what your system has in total, the (worse) alternative is to disable the download cache. This is possible via the `server.cfg` configuration file, but not recommended. The effect of this setting is that the nexus container is not started, but each new build of your project re-downloads the dependencies from the internet.

For more information, please refer to this operations guide for Cx Server https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/doc/operations/operations-guide.md

Best regards

Florian

Comment: Thank you, @FlorianWilhelm. I updated Docker, gave it nearly 4.5 GB memory to run and I think this helped solved the problem.